# Preferences and reasons for the use of "prey" as a verb instead of "predate"?

Tags: verbs, synonyms, word-usage, science

As an entomologist I must write and review manuscripts every day. English is my second language, and luckily the main idiom for scientific writing and discussion.
I am often of two minds about the best choice of verb for conveying "consuming another animal" — either "prey on/upon" or "predate". In fact for a long time I thought the second "latinized" usage was a common mistake. 
What do others think, please?

Comment: [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=predate) (which you really should have checked and quoted) gives 1974 as the date _predate_ was coined as a back-formation from predator. But if the string is accepted as a word, it doesn't matter if it's been around for 300 days or 300 years. While @Mark Ch's answer is correct, I believe that in a certain register 'predate' may be the more common term. You really need to check a style guide relevant to the work you are reviewing / writing; this becomes POB.

Comment: Probably because of the other pronunciation and meaning of *predate*.

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth says, it doesn't matter which [predates](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predate) the other :P

Comment: If it were me I’d only use *predate* in sentences like: “The T. Rex predates chickens” and not “The fox predates chickens”  otherwise it’s too confusing.

Comment: @Jim - Ah, but that raises the religious question:  Did the T. Rex predate humans??

Comment: @HotLicks - I’d have to ask Bill Nye about that.

Comment: @HotLicks, that is two questions rolled into one, such that answering either in the affirmative is almost necessarily to answer the other in the negative. On the other hand, by Plato's famous definition the tyrannosaur *was* human.

Comment: @BrianDonovan  "Paleontologists have long debated this. A string of studies in the past decade have pointed to the potential widespread presence of either feathers or fuzz-like proto-feathers in dinosaur species. In 2012, paleontologists found that a T. rex relative, Yutyrannus huali, had filamentous feathers. If a relative had feathers, why not the king of reptiles itself?"  

Read more: http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/five-things-we-dont-know-about-tyrannosaurus-rex-180951072/#8fxQQKSGD4IHuyV3.99

Comment: *Predate* can be used is in few areas where *prey on* doesn't work well. *prey on* focuses on the victim, where *predate* is more general in referring to an act of predation. For instance, you can do a study on predated bird nests or predated turtle nests. One often sees both predated and preyed upon in the same work. And *predated* is more amenable to passive constructions.

Comment: @Phil Sweet thanks for a practical point of view. I mostly want to make sure others are not flinching at the use of "predate" in that sense, as I used to in the past. Edwin Ashworth : generally there are no set standards for such vocabulary outside of jargon in scientific literature but as Jim jokingly stated some constructions do sound funny in an evolutionary context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Predate* is virtually never used in spoken English, even though *predator* is a commonly used word. *Prey on* is frequently used in day to day spoken English in the UK.

*Predate* is so uncommon in spoken English that someone is unlikely to even understand what it means.

Comment: *Predated* is very common in monographs and ecological treatises.

Comment: @PhilSweet which are both forms of *written* English

Comment: The question concerns manuscripts, yes? Actually, I guess it doesn't say it is about manuscript usage, but I think that is what the asker wants.

Comment: Happy to delete my answer if I've missed the point, or you can vote down if it's wrong, or whatever, no problem

Comment: Not being a native speaker, I indeed grew up thinking predate as a verb for preying was a mistake. However once I corrected that on someone else's manuscript and the other part was outraged and sent me the links to online dictionaries. However I see there are personal views on this matter.